# right distance of background-position in CSS

Tags: html, css, background, slice

I worked on a CMS and I want to have diffrent Buttons for special editings.
I created a small examplefile wich looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml:lang="de" lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>demo</title>
<style>
/* --- "breadcrumbs" --- */
ul.path         {margin:0;
                 padding:0;
                 padding-bottom:19px;
                 zoom:1;
                 overflow:hidden;}
ul.path li      {list-style-type:none;
                 list-style-position:outside;
                 height:28px;
                 overflow:hidden;
                 float:left;
                 margin-right:2px;
                 font-size:85%;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 line-height:19px;
                 background:url(hor.png) no-repeat left -90px;}
ul.path li.cur  {padding-left:10px;
                 background:url(hor.png) no-repeat left -60px;}
ul.path a       {padding:0 15px 0 0;
                 overflow:hidden;
                 float:left;
                 font-weight:normal;
                 height:26px;
                 padding-top:2px;
                 color:#fff;
                 text-decoration:none;
                 background:url(hor.png) no-repeat right -90px;}
ul.path li.cur a {color:#FFF;
                 font-weight:bold;
                 background:url(hor.png) no-repeat -180px -60px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="path">
    <li><a href="#">Webdevelopment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">programming</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">database</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">modeling</a></li>
    <li class="cur"><a href="#">Dezign</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an png Background image which looks like this
[Background images with tiffrent right corners http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/1849/hor.png](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/1849/hor.png)
The result looks like this:
[result http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/774/resultr.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/774/resultr.png)
The goal is to get a diffrent right corner, but my tries to set a negative distance dosen't work. Can somone give me an explanation?
And much more interesting can somone give me an workaround, that fix the mistake in the class cur?

Comment: I think you should your CSS questions in http://doctype.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are setting a negative distance that gives you a piece in the middle of the first background. If you use a position like -250px you will get closer, but to get it exact you have to either set a fixed width on the link or use an image where the desired background is at the right edge.

Comment: oh i checked it with a negetive margin too. The result is unfortunatly the same. It's right that the solution works with right. But in this case I need for ervery right corners a special row and my wish was to have for erery color one row and for ervery right corner one special position, where I can find the correct corner.
When I read the specification of CSS Backgroundposition I thought, that I can give a negative value to reach the right corner. But it seem, that this dosen't work. unfortunatly. Maybe someone know an other solution. But thank you, for your answer.

Comment: @Lara: Even if you use a negative position, it's still the position for the left edge of the element. If you don't want to specify a width for the element, the only background position that you can use to specify the right edge is "right". So, the only solution if you don't want to specify a width, is to rearrange the image so that you get all the right edges at the right edge of the image.